# Ubuntu 22.04 and 20.04 keeps freezing on Dell Vostro 3481

Tags: 20.04, dell, 22.04, freeze, lockup

First time poster, and also a complete Linux noob (this is my first time ever trying to use/install linux), so please forgive any shortcomings in this post/question.

Device Data:

```
device - Dell Vostro 3481 (08CF)
RAM - 8GiB SODIMM DDR4
RAM - 8GiB SODIMM DDR4
processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7020U CPU
storage        ADATA LEGEND 740 250GB NVMe
```

The machine ran ok until I installed Ubuntu 22.04. The installation went smoothly, but within a few minutes of rebooting, signing in, and getting familiar with Ubuntu, it completely froze - nothing short of hard resetting worked. Things went downhill from there and the device would continually freeze within five minutes of booting up.

Steps I took:

1. Wiping the ssd and reinstalling ubuntu 22.04
2. Updated the BIOS
3. Tested RAM using memtest86
4. Hours of googling/reviewing other askubuntu threads.

There are several similar threads about freezing/lock-up issues in both 20.04 and 22.04, but from what I can tell a lot of the issues related to nvidia drivers. As far as I know, my machine is using an integrated graphics card.

Eventually I found a thread that mentioned Ubuntu 20.04 would be better for machines with older hardware. I wiped the SSD, installed 20.04, and ran into the exact same problem. This time I found this website: https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/bugs.html. It is for Linux Mint but I tried tip #25 as it relates to intel.

After changing the grub max_cstate value to 1 and rebooting the freezing issues seems to have resolved, but now I am plagued by dozens of system errors. They all look something like this:

```
watchdog:BUG:soft lockup-CPU#1 stuck for 205s![kworker/1:5/460]
```

While I am relieved that the machine is no longer freezing (For now), I can't help but be concerned that I have just caused further issues with the max_cstate fix.

Any insight, help, tips, and/or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same freezing problem on an HP desktop, but following the linux mint intel freezing solution made it worse; after reboot my machine was freezing every 5 seconds or so, for ~10 seconds each time.

What has finally fixed it for me is using the top bar Gnome menu to set to Performance mode, instead of Balanced, how it was set before.

-Correction, upon boot today my machine froze in the same way. So I went for the next thing I could think of, the fact that I get a message on boot saying that TPM chip could not be communicated with. Went in to bios and deactivated TPM, and my machine does not freeze any more.

Comment: There are many causes for a system to freeze or "appears" to freeze.